# repeated values in custom picklist

Tags: apex, visualforce

I am binding account object field type values to a Picklist.

But when I run the Visualforce Page I see repeated values, for ex. Customer-Direct value is repeated 4 times. Why could that be? How do I fix it?

Class:

```
public class someclass {
    public String strSelected{get;set;}

    public List<SelectOption> options{get;set;}

    public List<SelectOption> getValues() {
        strSelected='';

        options=new List<SelectOption>();
        options.add(new selectOption('', '- None -'));
        for(Account a:[select ID,Type from Account]) {
            if (a != NULL) {
                options.add(new SelectOption(a.ID,a.Type));
            }
        }
        return options;
    }
```

Page:

```
<apex:page controller="someclass">
    <apex:form >
        <apex:selectList value="{!strSelected}" 
            multiselect="false" 
            size="1">
            <apex:selectOptions value="{!Values}"/>
        </apex:selectList>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/70576/discussion-on-question-by-krishna-casukhela-repeated-values-in-custom-picklist).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of running a query to get the values from the database, try getting the values of your picklist from your schema. Once you have a list of your picklist values, you can easily sort, filter, or perform any other operation on your data based on these values.

For example, putting your records into a `Map<String, List<Account>>`, where the String is a valid type value. From here, its easy enough to iterate over each key & display the lists of accounts in a page block table.

Taken from a [Developer Article](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2008/12/using-the-metadata-api-to-retrieve-picklist-values.html):

> Lets say we have a custom object called `OfficeLocation__c`. `OfficeLocation__c` contains a number of fields, one of which is a picklist of country values called, creatively enough, `Country__c`. Our customer requirements are to include the picklist of countries on a Visualforce page which uses a custom controller. The first thing we need to do, within our controller is use the `getDescribe()` method to obtain information on the `Country__c` field:
>
> ```
> Schema.DescribeFieldResult fieldResult = OfficeLocation__c.Country__c.getDescribe();
> ```
>
> We know that `Country__`c is a picklist, so we want to retrieve the picklist values:
>
> ```
> List<Schema.PicklistEntry> ple = fieldResult.getPicklistValues();
> ```
>
> The only thing left for us to do is map the picklist values into an `<apex:selectOptions>` tag can use for display. Here is the entire method from our controller to do this:
>
> ```
> public List<SelectOption> getCountries()
> {
>   List<SelectOption> options = new List<SelectOption>();
>
>    Schema.DescribeFieldResult fieldResult = OfficeLocation__c.Country__c.getDescribe();
>    List<Schema.PicklistEntry> ple = fieldResult.getPicklistValues();
>
>    for( Schema.PicklistEntry f : ple)
>    {
>       options.add(new SelectOption(f.getLabel(), f.getValue()));
>    }       
>    return options;
> }
> ```